# Syntax/error checking breaks in FlexBuilder/Flashbuilder with class libraries over Samba?

Tags: actionscript-3, flexbuilder, gumbo

We have our class libraries on a shared server we access via Samba (and ssh for command line). Sadly, several features seem to fail in both Flex Builder and Flash Builder/Gumbo with this setup. For example, we no longer get automatic syntax and error checking. Anyone familiar with this issue and able to suggest a solution? Thanks!

Comment: A colleague suggested trying MacFUSE with sshfs. It was a nice idea, but the outcome has been the same.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this problem had nothing to do with our abstruse setup. I had simply forgotten to create a reference to the top-level class in the application file (bear in mind that with this setup the Flex project folder exists only to satisfy FB's need to place project files somewhere...all the real code is off on the server). Once this was done, all normal services were restored.